# How to scroll ol to the bottom dynamically when success function is clld?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a ol list like so

```
 <ol id="result" class="chat">
        <?php
        include("load.php");
        ?>

    </ol>
```

is that file i have a list item like so

```
  <li class="other">
        <!--<div class="avatar"><img src=" " draggable="false"/></div>-->
      <div class="msg red">
        <p><?php echo $message; ?></p>
        <!--<p>Te vienes a cenar al centro? <emoji class="pizza"/></p>-->
        <time>20:17</time>
      </div>
   </li>
```

my issue is when a person send a message the list does not scroll to the bottom automatically  this is what i have tried

```
 $("#result").animate({scrollTop: $('#result').prop("scrollHeight")}, 500);
```

Comment: use raw Javascript ````window.scrollTo(x, y)````

Answer (score 1):

this is the right syntax

```js
$("body, html").animate({
  scrollTop: $("#result").offset().top
}, 500);
```

```css
body {
  height: 700px;
  padding-top: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="result">test</div>
```

Comment: hmm this scrolls to the top instead to the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Here are two more options:

1. use pure html and make a link with a `#`.
2. use plain javascript and use the `scrollIntoView()` function

```js
document.getElementById("jumpButton").addEventListener("click", jumper);

function jumper() {
  var e = document.getElementById("submit");
  e.scrollIntoView();
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> <a href="#submit"> click here to scroll. </a> </li>
  <li> Or a button <button id="jumpButton">Jump</button>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
  <li> blah blah blah </li>
</ol>

<button id='submit'>Click me</button>
```